# Java one critical section multiple semaphores

Tags: java, multithreading, frameworks, semaphore

I need to know, if there is some framework which could provide me this funcionality. I have one critical section in one method and I need few other methods wait until this critical section is executed and finished. If critical section is not active, those methods should fluently work.

And if critical section is entered only when no thread is in semaphored methods.

Such as:

```
public class Worker {

    private Critical critical = null;
    private CriticalDependent dep1 = null; 
    private CriticalDependent dep2 = null;

    public Worker() {

        critical = new Critical();
        dep1 = critical.registerDependent();
        dep2 = critical.registerDependent();

    }
    public void critical() {
         critical.enter();
         critical.waitForClearToGo();

         // protected unique code
         // change resource handle etc

         critical.exit();
    }

    public void dependent1() {
         critical.checkWaitAndUnsetClearToGo(this.dep1);

         // some dependent code
         // use resource handle

         critical.setClearToGo(this.dep1);
    }

    public void dependent2() {
         critical.checkWaitAndUnsetClearToGo(this.dep2);

         // some dependent code
         // use resource handle

         critical.setClearToGo(this.dep2);
    }
}
```

I can figure out some solution, but I prefer to use existing framework. And I cannot find existing one. Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

Comment: Well, does it really help me to fullfill my task? I think it does not. I want my critical section automatically set red lights on semaphored code and start only and only when no thread is in semaphored section. 

Will this semaphore allow me to reach?

Answer (score 2):

Use the standard Java [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).

Comment: Please, can you give me some hint?

Comment: Did you check the link?

Comment: Yes, I've already checked - I'm not sure if it checks to my scenario. For me provided code is not that straightforward like for you. I will check for more examples...

Comment: Since permit count is integer and not an object... I don't know, how to use it in my scenario. I have made slight changes to my scenario to provide more information on what I really need. 

I don't think Semaphore alone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Java's [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) as already told by Erik.
However you need one with 2 permits, so that your 2 dependent methods can run at the same time, but the critical section will block both of the dependent methods.

```
Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(2, true);  // Make it fair, so critical section won't wait unnecessarily

public void critical() {
    semaphore.acquire(2); // Blocks both dependents, waiting if they're not available
    ...
    semaphore.release(2);
}

public void dep1() {
    semaphore.acquire(); // Blocks only if critical() has both permits
    ...
    semaphore.release();
}

public void dep2() {
    semaphore.acquire(); // Ditto, dep1() can have the other permit
    ...
    semaphore.release();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I have just tested, that this example doesn't work like I wish to. This code allows running dep1 and dep2 during critical. Either semaphore is not good for this or you provided wrong example or I have made mistake rewriting it?

Comment: `Start ...
     thrd 1 dep1 System time=1449939961641
     thrd 2 dep1 System time=1449939961641
     thrd 2 dep2 System time=1449939961891
     thrd 1 dep2 System time=1449939961891
     thrd 2 result 0 : 0
     Critical enter , System time=1449939962141
     thrd 1 result 0 : 0
     thrd 1 dep1 System time=1449939962141... this should not happen if it worked
     Critical done , System time=1449939963141`

Comment: I posted dump from my test code. It's obvious that dep1 is called and executed during critical ... so...?

Comment: Then you've made a mistake. Naturally all the threads should work on the same `Semaphore` object, so if you've got multiple `Worker` classes, you'll need rethink your approach. The example works perfectly for a single `Worker` with 3 threads working on it. If you need more threads, you can increase the permits to something excessive like 1000, and make sure that `critical()` acquires all of them.

Comment: Strange. 

I've made class test, which holds semaphore, has all three methods mentioned above implemented and has entrypoint. Dep1 and Dep2 returns integer, which is increased by one each time critical is called. Those methods acts exactly like you've described.

Class test has internal class extending thread with constructor containing reference to class test and run method, in which it is calling dep1, dep2 in a loop.  

In entrypoint I create test and two threads, wait until threads are done. 

Result is shown above - when critical is entered, threads happily access dep1 & dep2.

Comment: Thank you. It seems good. I've been releasing semaphore twice in dep2. Now it works fine. If I hadn't done this error before I didn't have to ask this question.